# How to call groovy inner class

Tags: groovy-console

This is my code, and I try to call the method in the inner class as shown below (the last line, ic = new oc.Inner()). But I get error.

I am using groovy console, and according to groovy documentation I expect that the Inner class can be called from outer class. I am not sure about the syntax.

```
class Outer {    
      private String privateStr = 'some string'  
       def callInnerMethod() {        
        new Inner().methodA()            
      }      
        class Inner { 
            def methodA() { 
                println "${privateStr}."       
            }     
       } 
}

Outer oc = new Outer()
ic = new oc.Inner()
```

This is what I get as result:

```
startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 14: unable to resolve class oc.Inner 
 @ line 14, column 6.
   ic = new oc.Inner()
        ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def oc = new Outer()
def ic = new Outer.Inner(oc)
```

https://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_creating_instances_of_non_static_inner_classes

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def ic = new Outer.Inner()
```

This will likely only work if your inner class is static.